# How to recompile framework created using carthage with latest xcode version?

Tags: ios, xcode, carthage

I created some frameworks on my own using Xcode 8.2.1 with Carthage package manager. When I try to use this framework in Xcode 8.3.3 I am getting the error below:

> Module compiled with Swift 3.0.2 cannot be imported in Swift 3.1

I tried rebuilding the created framework using Xcode 8.3.3 and did `carthage update` in my existing project in which I am trying to use the framework. Still it throws the same error. Do I need to create the framework again using Xcode 8.3.3 in order to get rid of this error? Or is there a way to re-compile the existing framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was my default Xcode selection path was set to Xcode 8.2.1.

So every time I built the framework using `carthage build --no-skip-current`, it was building with Xcode 8.2.1.

I changed my Xcode selection path to point to Xcode 8.3.3 by using the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Now the framework has been updated and I am able to access my framework in Xcode 8.3.3 without any issue.